# Не работает объединение текста из нескольких файлов

Tags: python-3.x

Есть n текстовых файлов, в каждом из которых разное количество строк, необходимо скомбинировать их между собой, следующим образом:

Строки 1 файла:

```
part1a
part1b
```

Строки 2 файла:

```
part2a
part2b
part2c
```

На выходе:

```
part1a part2a
part1a part2b
part1a part2c
part1b part2a
```

и т.д.

```
with open('file4.txt', 'r+') as res, open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2, open('file3.txt') as f3:
    for line1 in f1:
        line1 = line1.rstrip('\n')
        for line2 in f2:
            line2 = line2.rstrip('\n')
            for line3 in f3:
                res.write(line1 + ' ' + line2 + ' ' + line3)
```

Результат получается такой:

```
part1a part2a part3a
part1a part2a part3b
part1a part2a part3c
```

Почему-то не выводятся комбинации со строками первого файла кроме первой, второго файла кроме первой.

Comment: можно расчитывать на то, что все файлы одновременно спокойно поместятся в памяти? PS у вас результат вроде бы как раз такой, который вам необходим, судя по описанию...

Comment: Не хватает строк c комбинациями part1b, part2b.
Планировал использовать для получения комбинаций с большими колчествами строк, что делать в таком случае? (Если результом должно быть несколько миллионов строк)

Comment: rstrip('\n') - почитайте как работает эта функция

Comment: Удаляет символы переноса строки, как раз чтобы не было результата вида:
    `part1a
    part2a
    part3a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну проблема очевидна, вам нужно по новой открывать файл. Потому что после первого цикла у вас указатель в файле оказывается в конце. Также почему у вас файл с результатами с режимом **r+** ? Должно быть **w** или **a**

```
with open('file4.txt', 'w') as res, open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2, open('file3.txt') as f3:
    for line1 in f1:
        line1 = line1.rstrip('\n')
        for line2 in f2:
            line2 = line2.rstrip('\n')
            for line3 in f3:
                line3 = line3.rstrip('\n')
                res.write(line1 + ' ' + line2 + ' ' + line3)
            f3.seek(0)
        f2.seek(0)
```

**Либо**

```
with open('file4.txt', 'w') as res:
    for line1 in open('file1.txt'):
        line1 = line1.rstrip('\n')
        for line2 in open('file2.txt'):
            line2 = line2.rstrip('\n')
            for line3 in open('file3.txt'):
                line3 = line3.rstrip('\n')
                res.write(line1 + ' ' + line2 + ' ' + line3)
```

Comment: Честно говоря я не видел разницы между r+, w, a, т.к. моей целью было открыть файл на запись, и о положении указателя не задумывался.

Comment: Подскажите, а что если файлов которые нужно скомбинировать не 3, а 100? Подход с написанием 100 for циклов кажется не рациональным. И   что, если и файлов много, и строк в каждом файле тоже, т.е. результатом будет миллионы строк, подходит ли тогда такое решение?

Comment: Нет конечно, писать 100 вложенных циклов бессмысленно. Используйте рекурсию. А еще держать открытым кучу файлов плохо!
Так что сначала я бы рекомендовал все считать в память и потом формировать файл

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть список файлов. Делаете итератор для списка. Далее сама функция, которая проходит по файлам и собирает строку. Функция принимает промежуточную строку и файл. В функции определяется переменная, которая хранит номер строки, чтобы можно было закрывать файл, пока открыт другой. Логика функции: если в файле есть следующая строка, читаем строку, увеличиваем номер строки. Конкатенируем полученную строку с входной, вызываем функцию и предаем новую строку и следующий файл. Если файла нет, выводим строку.
Пишу с телефона, поэтому нет возможности описать кодом.

Comment: Когда будет более удобный доступ, дополните ответ кодом.